# Best distro for using Google Docs on old computer

Tags: wifi, nvidia, browser

I've got an old computer that had XP on it.  It's got an AMD Athlon 1.1 GHz processor, 1 GB of PC133 RAM, a 20GB IDE hard drive, a Belkin wireless card with the RT2560 chipset, and an NVidia TNT2 graphics card.  What is the best Linux distribution given that my only goal is to use Google Doc's word processor for document that are several hundred pages of plain text?

I tried Ubuntu 12.04 and found everything ran very slowly and that I couldn't get the wireless card to work with my WPA2 network with a hidden SSID.  (It repeatedly asked me for my password.)  I thought the slowness might be due to problems with the nouveau drier.  I tried following some instructions on various sites to get both to work, but I've given up.  None of the instructions seem to work.

All I want to do is use Google Docs.  I do a lot of writing and have been using Google Docs, though I work as a software engineer.

If the answer is "Ubuntu should work just fine", I'll head over to their stack exchange site and start asking questions.

Comment: Welcome! Firstly, your question could be closed because it is *too broad*. Beside that, I recommend you Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu an am a user on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com). If you have issues installing and such, then you may ask there. Good luck!

Comment: It's not Ubuntu that is the problem, but it's window manager/desktop environment that uses a lot of resources. Take a look at Xubuntu or even Lubuntu, and see this question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar

Comment: @terdon Ubuntu does not require Unity.  If that's the problem, recommend another *DE* not a whole other distro, or explain what is actually "bloated" instead of throwing out the baby with the bathwater.    Otherwise, you are  propagating the misunderstanding that a distro == a DE and vice versa.  **XFCE is a "full fledged DE",** albeit more lightweight than most others, and you're free to use that on ubuntu.  LXDE is even lighter, I believe.

Comment: Can I make a point here?  You're asking which distro to use, but you've tagged this as Ubuntu.  I think there's a problem with that tag, as that makes this an "Ubuntu" question, rather than a "What distro is best for this" question.  Also, Lucio makes a valid point, this is a very broad question.

Comment: I can't seem to find it in the FAQ, but I'm pretty sure "best" questions are discouraged as opinion based and non-constructive.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, all.  I will check out AskUbuntu and give Lubuntu a shot.  I suppose I asked a broad question because it seemed narrow to me, though I realized that's not the case.  I'm not a regular Linux user yet, and I think I got disoriented with the sheer amount of information out there.  So thank you also for the patience with the excessively broad question.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can give [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) a try. To quote some of its features:

> - Runs from RAM, making it unusually fast even in old PCs and in netbooks with solid state storage media.
> - Very low minimum system requirements.
> - Boot time is well under a minute, 30-40 seconds in most systems.
> - Includes a wide range of applications: wordprocessors, spreadsheets, internet browsers, games, image editors and many utilities. Extra software in the form of dotpets. There is a GUI Puppy Software Installer included.

However, I have never used it. So, not sure if there would be any problems with the Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ubuntu, with Firefox works just fine. I have used text and spreadsheet. 
Make sure JavaScript is enabled.

You need a google account, but you probably already have that.

Comment: The OP's issue is old hardware. Ubuntu/Unity won't run well on it.

Comment: *Unity* may not run well, but there is no reason *ubuntu* shouldn't, sans Unity.

Comment: @goldilocks Then Lubuntu or Xubuntu should be suggested, Ubuntu Gnome has some heavy requirements too, Lubuntu or Xubuntu are much lighter here.

Comment: @ThomasW. : Sure, but you are not required to use either Gnome or Unity with Ubuntu, and you do not need to use L- or X- ubuntu to use XFCE or LXDE (although they may make it simpler).  I'm objecting to the confusion of apples (distro) with oranges (UI).

Comment: @goldilocks you've added to the confusion here, then.  Installing ubuntu and then adding XFCE or LXDE isn't exactly a "easy" thing to do, if they want just XFCE or LXDE it's easier for them to just install the derivative rater than dealing with adding additional UI packages.  (however correct your distinction may be, my point is simplicity of getting the desktop environments via installing the specific derivative, not comparing apples and oranges)

Comment: @ThomasW. : It certainly isn't a "hard" thing to do either, ~5 minutes subject to download time.  Again, I think this is a very important distinction to make, since most people who don't already understand it are most likely thinking in terms of the very different, much more rigid, Windows/Mac world.  If you *know* you want ubuntu and you *know* you want XFCE and you haven't installed anything, absolutely go with Xubuntu.  But if you aren't sure what you want, trying things out by *re-installing* various distros (which is where this otherwise leads) is just silly and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

1 Ghz core + 1 GB of RAM is plenty, you certainly do not need to consider special "small" distros unless you have a yearning to experiment.  Your system is simply *not* a small one, linux wise.

Also: Generally, "small" refers to the *install size* (i.e., hard disk space used) and much less (or not at all) the actual amount of RAM required, etc.  I have (headless) systems running mainstream distros (including ubuntu) that run 24/7 on < 100 MB RAM.

What you do want to consider is the GUI software stack you are running.  While the easiest way to get a light stack is to choose a distro that prioritizes minimizing resource use, it is not necessary.

For example, if ubuntu is your preference, install a headless server version and then add the Xorg server and a DE ([desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System)) or WM ([window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager#X_window_managers)).  Note that the former generally includes the latter by necessity, so stand-alone WM's are almost by definition much lower profile than DEs.  If all you need to run is one or two applications, you don't really need a DE at all; the major difference will be that without a DE, you'll probably want to install a file manager/browser of some sort (they usually go along with the DE).

There are numerous comparisons of linux oriented DEs and WMs on line; probably you want to avoid the most feature rich ones like GNOME and KDE and opt for one such as XFCE or LXDE.  There is a ubuntu distribution which uses XFCE by default, Xubuntu, and one which uses LXDE, Lubuntu.

However, just to restate: *any* mainstream distro will allow you to run *any* mainstream DE/WM.  Or none at all. You just have to configure it.